# dataTable().fnGetNodes() is automatically sorting the datatable if first element is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using datatable and append 3 textbox and 1 dropdown and 1 ADD button on button click. I'm adding data in existing table and so on issue is when i get all rows using `$('#datatable').dataTable().fnGetNodes()` is automatically sorting the datatable elements if first element is blank, and if all entered element is there then it won't sort.

```
var rows = $("#datatable_example1").dataTable().fnGetNodes();

for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var mapObj = new Object();
    mapObj.taskCode = $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(1)").html();
    mapObj.tasksName = $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(0)").html();
    mapObj.description = $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(2)").html();
    mapObj.moduleId = $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(3)").attr('id');
    mapObj.menuPath = $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(4)").html();

    datatableArray.push(mapObj);
}
```

Here I get the rows of the datatable from the first row because the first row contains the textboxes and buttons if datatable sorted then the first row is automatically placed last. Is there any solution while getting  `$().dataTable().fnGetNodes()` will not sort automatically?

Comment: Could you show an example of the markup, i.e the <table>?? It is not so clear how the table looks like. Also, do you use dataTables 1.9.x or 1.10.x?

Comment: here i mention in my question that I’m using data-table

Comment: But **which version of dataTables**? It is important since you can do it a lot easier than above, but in different ways according to version. Also, provide an example of the markup, eg the table. It is not clear at all what "blank" is, where and when a "textbox" is inserted and so on. An example says 1000 times more than a vague description, and why not show the markup since the markup is essentiel for solving the problem anyway?

Comment: i am using jquery (version 1.5) data-table. Tex-boxes and button added using js method

var rows = $("#datatable_example1").dataTable().fnGetNodes();

when get all nodes of data-table it automatically sort all elements of datatable and put text-boxes and button at last row

Comment: 1.5.x is 6 years old! I would really encourage you to upgrade. Anyway, no one can help you out if they not are able to reproduce your scenario. How should anyone could be sure a solution is correct without having a an example to base a solution on?  If you not want to clarify the question, then peace with that. All I can say is that `fnGetNodes` itself under no circumstances are sorting the result.

Comment: okay thank you @davidkonard
give me ur mail id i will forward my js/js pages so you can understand well and yes my jquery version is 1.8.2